# Java Dependent Projects Error When Running Maven Install

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, installation

I am getting the following error when running maven install

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project Ice-Redalert-Web: Compilation failure [ERROR] /D:/ProjectCode/RedAlert ICE/property-builder-front-ice/src/main/java/com/informationcatalyst/redalert/webapplication/service/IceApplicationBuilderImpl.java:[22,1] package com.informationcatalyst.icekeywords does not exist [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles

There are two projects. The main project and one it depends on. When running maven install on my laptop, the above error comes up. However when my co-worker takes an identical copy of both projects and runs maven install it works just fine.

There must be something wrong on my setup for this to be an issue. I don't know where to start. Myself and co-worker who has lots of java experience checked the setup and naming and can't see a problem. But there clearly is an issue.

The main project has the dependency as pom entry as

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.undergroundit</groupId>
    <artifactId>train</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

The header on the pom relating to the above reference is

```
<groupId>com.undergroundit</groupId>
<artifactId>train</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>train</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

I am using Eclipse, but I get the same issue arising in Intellij.

We checked the .m2 folder for the contents to make sure it was matching the pom entries.

Any guidance on what to check or what the problem might be is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turns out to be that although the dependent project would compile in the IDE it wasn't including the class files. Therefore the projects depending on it didn't have enough information to use the dependency.

The ... in the mainClass element below is to anonymise the name.

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
 <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                   <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <outputDirectory>
                           ${project.build.directory}/lib
                       </outputDirectory>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <archive>
                   <manifest>
                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                       <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                       <mainClass>...</mainClass>
                   </manifest>
               </archive>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to either run the build with clean and/or to delete the maven .m2 cache. I've had similar errors with the maven cache.
Are you sure you and your co-worker have the identical source? The error message suggest a missing package, which may indicate that you are looking at the wrong error.

Comment: Yes we cleared the cache, made use of maven update. Also the project is the same because I Zipped up both projects. Just tried it all again after a reboot and same issue.

Comment: @Jens Scharmann Suggestion should be posted in the comments section not in the answer section.

Comment: Have you tried using maven from the command line? This would definitly exclude all dependencies which would be availabla via M2E (I'm not sure if IntelliJ as a corresponding feature).
@NagarajKandoor I don't have enough reputation to post in the comments...

Comment: @NagarajKandoor yes but the alternative was not to try to help. If people downvote me, I also cannot write comments in the future, so this would not help either :).

Comment: I didn't realise that command line install worked differently.
Tried this : First command line mvn install for the dependency, then again for the main project.  
I got the same error as before.

Comment: You should try mvn clean install

Comment: I tried maven clean, and maven install on dependency then the same again for the main project. Same error. 
(Thanks for the replies so far)

Comment: As suggested earlier: In which project is the package com.informationcatalyst.icekeywords which is declared as missing?

Comment: Okay so I tried to anonymise the pom entries above, but forgot to anonymise the error message.

The main project is saying the icekeywords is missing. The dependent project okay.

Comment: The groupid would be com.informationcatalyst and not com.undergroundit

Comment: I meant the java package not the groupID and artifactID. I suppose you don't have compilation errors in eclipse. Is the dependency in POM defined at the correct position (e.g. in the general dependencies or your executed profile)?

Comment: The property-builder-front-ice is the project which has the missing package, This is the main project.

Comment: And where is this package supposed to be? In the given dependency?

Comment: The package com.informationcatalyst.redalert.webapplication.service from the main project is trying to do this import : import com.informationcatalyst.icekeywords.*; from the dependent project.

Comment: Ok, these were all my typical errors I encountered so far with maven. The error suggest that package com.informationcatalyst.icekeywords itself is missing. Maybe it is not part of your generate jar or if you use something like OSGi it might not be exported. Do you have both projects in your Eclipse workspace? I woult try to close the dependency so it loads the maven one (maybe a maven/project clean is required). And you may look in the jar in your .m2 folder.

Comment: Thanks Jens, Both projects are in the workspace. I will explore the ideas you mention, especially OSG.